# GD Color Replacement

Tags: php, gd

This is killing me..

The Image has a background of solid red, a foreground of solid grey. On the edges of the foreground there is some anti-aliasing from grey to white.

What I need to do is change the foreground color to a user specified color and the red to transparent. This is easy enough using imagecolorcloset + imagecolorset/imagecolortransparent. The problem is the antialasing part.

I believe I need to loop through the pixels in the image. This would appear to work: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php#98153

I believe that I now need to determine the color difference between the foreground color and the anti aliased color.

So...

Foreground Color = rgb (153, 153, 153)

Anti-Alias Pixel = rgb (173, 173, 173)

New Color = rgb (0, 0, 255)

**How do I determine the difference in color between the AA Pixel and the Foreground Color then apply it to the new color?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: Turns out it's to do with factors**

The anti-alias value should be the same factor so

```
<?

   //old foreground colour
   $of = array (220, 220, 220);
   //old anti alias colour
   $oaa = array (110, 110, 110);

   //factors
   $factors = array ($of[0]/$oaa[0], $of[1]/$oaa[1], $of[2]/$oaa[2]);

   //new foreground
   $nf = array (156, 34, 34);
   //new anti alias
   $naa = array($nf[0]/$factors[0], $nf[1]/$factors[1], $nf[2]/$factors[2]);

?>
```

Comment: This was my original thought but I believe this is incorrect. If new foreground color is 0, 0, 255. You would end up haveing 20, 20, 255 which would be a different color entirely.

Comment: Try the new answer, playing around with photoshop that seems to be correct